# Get all Files in a folder using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, microsoft-graph-files

Requirement - Need to access a particular File within a Document Library

File Path - host-name/sites/sitename/Shared Documents/Folder1/File1

I tried with these

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{host-name}/sites/{site-id}:/drives](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bhost-name%7D/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D:/drives)

- Got all the Document Library in that site

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{host-name}/sites/{site-id}:/drives/{drive-id}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bhost-name%7D/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D:/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root/children)

Tried with the above getting error, Bad request.

I am new to MS Graph, Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

As specified in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children, if you already have the drive-id than you can just make the following request to list the children:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children`

Or if you want to list the items in a sub-folder:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children`

To list the children based on the Path:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children`

In your case:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/Shared Documents/Folder1/File1:/children`

Answer (score 6):

Your example to To list the children based on the Path:

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root:/%7Bpath-relative-to-root%7D:/children)

How do you translate this to using GraphServiceClient on the server site using csharp?

For example, I am trying something like this:

var driveItems = await graphClient.Sites["mypersonalteamsite.sharepoint.com"].Drive.Root.{what else do I need to do specify the path?}.{Children?}.Request().GetAsync();

I know I have files and folders under https://mypersonalteamsite.sharepoint.com/IT
I want to get these using path.

So if I need to get file in the subfolder I can just use the path. eg. https://mypersonalteamsite.sharepoint.com/IT/mysubfolder/mysubsubfolder2/file.txt

Also if I need to get list of files & folders, I just like to use the path
eg. https://mypersonalteamsite.sharepoint.com/IT/mysubfolder/mysubsubfolder2/*

Comment: Have you to got the C# syntax to retrieve the files for the above scenario. I also struck with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all files within a subfolder which is stored in the default Shared Document library in a site, please use this endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/Folder1:/children

This is the returned web url for the endpoint, get the files list within "Folder1" subfolder:

[image]

Reference:

[Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just list all of the children in the root, because it includes everything (function, files, folders, annotations, enums, etc.) and if there are more than 200 items you won't get a list, you'll get a next link to use to parse through them all. Besides, you want one answer, right?

Based on your requirement, the best query is using a root path.

/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children

You can get that from the MS Graph documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope that helps, Peter